# Ubuntu 14.04. Lost wired connection and will not connect wireless, lost nm-applet and laptop will not shut down, now lost cd rom connection

Tags: wireless, 14.04, shutdown

I have been using Ubuntu 10.04 for a couple of years and I am new to Ubuntu terminal.

I performed my first Ubuntu OS installation a couple of weeks. 14.04

It is now my 4th installation because while I have fixed one thing, I have broken another.

First I was not able to connect to my wireless access point.

Now I cannot connect using a wired, or a wireless connection. I also managed to lose the `nm-applet`, and my laptop will not shut down unless I hold down the power key.

I was able to establish a connection using an wireless external USB. I also have access to a desktop to perform all checks.

I am loving the learning curve and Ubuntu, however now require some help to see what I have done as I have spent endless nights troubleshooting with no success.

My laptop is a HP dv6700 running Ubuntu 14.04.

Just to add after performing an upgrade I have also lost my cd rom. So I cant even do a re install. My start up disk creator doesn't seem to be functioning either.

I am not giving up. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Please run the script is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and am not sure what you mean by run the scrip.Do you mean to run a certain command in the terminal and then post the results here?

Comment: Yes click on the link in my previous comment and then read the directions in the accepted answer of that post.

Comment: computer@computer-HP-Pavilion-dv6700-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for computer: 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7667214/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Have I done the correct thing by posting some results above including the link. Please let me know if this is what you wanted me to do. Help appreciated